# Java linked list used in Stack

Tags: java

To improve a little bit myself in data structures i tried to design my own Stack. To do so I decided to use a linked list to let me use undefined length stacks (and because I come from C programming). My code is:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack stk = new Stack();
        obj buf_el;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean stop=false;
    do{
        String buffer= s.next();
        System.out.println("Created first buff");
        if(buffer.equals("exit")) stop=true;
        if(buffer.equals("pop")){
            buf_el = stk.pop();
            System.out.println("Element Popped from stack:\t\t[#]\t-->\t"+buf_el.field());
        }
        else if(buffer.equals("push")){
            obj pushed = new obj(s.next());
            stk.push(pushed);
            System.out.println("Element pushed in the stack:\t\t[#]\t<--\t"+pushed.field());
        }
        else if(buffer.equals("stats")) stk.stats();
        else if(buffer.equals("all")) stk.traverse();
    }
    while(stop==false);
    }
}

class obj{
    private String field = new String();
    private   obj next = null;
    private   obj back = null;
    obj (String field){
        this.field=field;
    }

    public obj() {

    }

    void concat(obj next){
        this.next=next;
        this.next.back=this;
    }
    void del(){
        this.next=null;
        this.back.concat(null);
    }
    obj next(){
        return this.next;
    }
    obj back(){
        return this.back;
    }
    String field(){
        return this.field;
    }
}

class Stack{
    private obj head = null;
    private obj tail = null;
    private int pops=0;
    private int pushes=0;
    void push(obj el){
        pushes++;
        if(this.head==null | this.tail==null){
            this.head = el;
            this.tail = el;
        }
        else{
            head.concat(el);
        }
    }
    obj pop(){
        if(head==null & tail==null) System.out.println("The stack is empty, Operation failed.");
        else{
            pops++;
            if(this.head==this.tail){
                System.out.println("This is the last element; the stack is empty now");
                obj ret=new obj(this.head.field());
                this.head=null;
                this.tail=null;
                return ret;
            }
            else{
                obj ret=new obj(this.head.field());
                this.head=this.head.back();
                return ret;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    void stats(){
        System.out.println("Number of pops\t||\t"+pops);
        System.out.println("Number of pushes\t||\t"+pushes);
        System.out.println("Length of the stack\t||\t"+(pushes-pops));
    }
    void traverse(){
        if(head==null & tail==null) System.out.println("The stack is empty, Operation failed");
        obj cursor=null;
        System.out.println("    TAIL");
        System.out.println("\t|");
        System.out.println("\t|");
        System.out.println("\t|");
        System.out.println("\tV");
        do {
            cursor=tail;
            System.out.println(cursor.field());
            System.out.println("\t|");
            System.out.println("\t|");
            System.out.println("\t|");
            System.out.println("\tV");
            cursor=cursor.next();
        }
        while(cursor!=null);
        System.out.println("    HEAD");
    }
}
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/Matagyah/MyStack/blob/differentwayofimput/Main.java)

But it has a big problem: when i push a new element it is overwritten on the previous element. Where is the error? Probably I misunderstood something related to the "by reference" practices in Java. Moreover, what methods would you use to make such a programm?

P.S. I know that there is a stack library, but I believe it would be good to code these things to improve my knowledge of the language.

Comment: At the first glace: `if(this.head==null | this.tail==null)` I don't think it is a good idea to overwrite __both__ with `el` when either of them is `null`.

Comment: also, note logical and ( && ) and or ( || ) operators (you are using bitwise operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made two changes to make ik work:

first in a push you have to make th new element head

```
void push(obj el) {
    pushes++;
    if (this.head == null | this.tail == null) {
        this.head = el;
        this.tail = el;
    } else {
        el.concat(head);
        head = el;
    }
}
```

second in o pop you must make the next element head

```
obj pop() {
    if (head == null & tail == null)
        System.out.println("The stack is empty, Operation failed.");
    else {
        pops++;
        if (this.head == this.tail) {
            System.out.println("This is the last element; the stack is empty now");
            obj ret = new obj(this.head.field());
            this.head = null;
            this.tail = null;
            return ret;
        } else {
            obj ret = new obj(this.head.field());
            this.head = this.head.next();
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**
didnt't check traverse, had to change it too:

```
void traverse() {
    if (head == null & tail == null)
        System.out.println("The stack is empty, Operation failed");
    obj cursor = null;
    System.out.println("    TAIL");
    System.out.println("\t|");
    System.out.println("\t|");
    System.out.println("\t|");
    System.out.println("\tV");
    cursor = tail;
    while (cursor != null) {
        System.out.println(cursor.field());
        System.out.println("\t|");
        System.out.println("\t|");
        System.out.println("\t|");
        System.out.println("\tV");
        cursor = cursor.back();
    }
    System.out.println("    HEAD");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to overwrite the function equalsTo in your Obj class; 
It should look like that :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(obj o){
    if (o.field.equalsTo(this.field) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

like that, this should work

```
 if(this.head==null | this.tail==null){
            this.head = el;
            this.tail = el;
        }
        else{
            head.concat(el);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen to issue in you code.First if you want to add to end then concat using tail and move the tail to current node.if you push t1 head and tail both point to same node after that t2 add and head will point to t1 and tail will t2.That part missing in your code.

```
tail.concat(el);
 tail=tail.next();
```

Second in traverse process loop initialize once out side loop

```
cursor=head;
```

Comment: You changed it the other way around, but forgot to correct pop too

Comment: I have checked push method .Any way Just I am wondering for stack why you just take one top and add all element in front ,that will be simple way to implement.